# Calling Java method from HTML link

Tags: java, javascript, html, twitter, hyperlink

I'm currently building a Twitter client in Java using the Twitter4J API. To create a Twitter "timeline", I am currently pulling data from Twitter such as profile images, tweets and usernames, then displaying them in a JTextPane, formatted using HTML. Code example below:

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

       try {
           List<Status> statuses = HandleEvents.instance().twitter.getHomeTimeline();

           out.append("<html>");

           for (Status status : statuses)
           {
               out.append("<img src=\"").append(status.getUser().getProfileImageURL())
                       .append("\" width=30 height=30><b>").append(status.getUser().getName())
                       .append(":</b> ").append(status.getText())
                       .append("<br><br>");
           }

           out.append("</html>");

           tweetsTextPane.setText(out.toString());
```

This displays a timeline of 20 tweets, separated by two line breaks. Under each tweet, I would like to place a simple  hyperlink, called "Retweet", which calls one of my Java methods - HandleEvents.instance().twitter.retweetStatus(status.getId())

How would I got about doing this? Can the call be made directly between the  tags, or do I have to make the call using JavaScript?

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: You need to explain the context in which the code above gets executed.  Is it client side in an applet, ... or called from Javascript?  Is it server-side?

Comment: Kind of [bad timing](http://arstechnica.com/software/news/2011/03/twitter-tells-third-party-devs-to-stop-making-twitter-client-apps.ars) to be building a Twitter client

Comment: @Stephen C - Apologies. This is a JButton action performed method in a client-side GUI. A "refresh" button is clicked, then this code is executed.

@Cameron - Agreed. This is a college project though, so I'll still get the credit :)

Comment: @Stephen C - Forgot to tag you in this comment earlier: No it's an application. The HTML is used only within the JTextPane for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to have a hyperlink do you? Since it's a Swing app you could just add a `JLabel` that only *looks* like a hyperlink (but if you put in a little effort, it could behave like one as well). Add a listener for mouse clicks on that `JLabel` and you've can hook your current handler there.

On the other hand, if you do want actual HTML links, what you can do is implement your own [HyperlinkListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/HyperlinkListener.html).

Here are a couple of examples:

- http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/HyperlinkListenerExample.htm
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/DemonstratingtheHyperlinkListener.htm
- http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12997

Comment: Ah, I had never thought about making clickable JLabels for each tweet. I just thought HTML hyperlinks would be the way to go. Many thanks for all the contributions. I've been refreshing the page and following all your suggestions!

Comment: I really should stop making so many changes - but I either spot a mistake or something new strikes right *after* I hit save! :)

Comment: Not at all! If you can spot your own mistakes or notice places where you can write something better, it means you're a good programmer! I'm going to try and throw in an array of 20 JLabels now alongside each tweet. Will worry about the event listening after that. Should be no bother!

Comment: Silly question (and one that I may figure out before you can answer), how does one add a JLabel to a JTextPane? 

edit - never mind, there was a bug in my code. I was correct all along!